# Alternative words for 'videotape'

Tags: word-usage

What word(s) can be used to discriminate between an audio recording and a 'video' recording?  For example, I used an ipad to record my students' group work, but I think that if I said, "I recorded my students' music", that could easily be understood as an audio recording. But I didn't 'videotape', because I used an ipad, however it is both audio/visual. Should I just use the word filmed? Like, "hey, let me show you a film I took of my students?" I feel like that sounds so old fashioned. When we watch Youtube what are we watching? "Do you want to watch a youtube video"?  Should we just agree that recordings that show visual are videos?

Comment: "I filmed my students' work" is perfectly acceptable. "I ipadded my students" would be wrong on so many levels :)

Comment: "Ipad in hand, my students' work was filmed"

Comment: What's wrong with what you put in quotes: a *video recording*? You didn't put *audio recording* in quotes, even though it, too, is not listed as a word. As a verb, you can simply say, "I recorded it to video," or "I made a video recording".

Answer (score 1):

It is understood that a video recording would usually be accompanied by sounds ("audio"). When we watch Youtube we are usually said to be watching a 'video'. If it is of short duration it can be called a 'video clip'. In British English, the act of recording a video is often called 'videoing'.

[Video (Oxford Dictionary)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/video)

Answer (score 0):

A definition of **video**:  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/video)

> A movie recorded electronically, usually including a soundtrack:

and a definition of **vid:**  [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vid) and [oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vid)

> a *video*

Recent Examples of **vid** from the Web - M-W lin.k

> In this slapstick dashcam **vid** posted by a Thai YouTube account, a 
>   motorcyclist faces certain injury when a truck ahead of him on the
>   highway loses a mattress ...
>
> Check out this awesome **vid** of the girls behind the scenes at their
>   shoot to see more of the girls' Mudd campaign.
>
> In the initial **vid**, Rihanna is seen slowly applying Body Lava onto
>   her shoulder, then buffing it slowly with a Kabuki brush.

Thus:

> "Hey, let me show you a **vid** I took of my students!

is increasingly being used.

Comment: 'video' is standard. I've never heard 'vid' before.

Comment: @Mitch from my research it appears to be 'in the lexicon'.

Comment: lbf, sure it may well exist, but you need to give perspective. ['vid' is much rarer than 'video'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=video%2C+vid&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). This answer highlights 'vid', to the detriment of 'video', as though it is __the__ answer. To someone who is new to English, or even to those with lots of experience, this would be extremely misleading.

Comment: @Mitch edited to preclude my answer as providing a word to the exclusion of all others.